# Google Cloud Build integration with Bitbucket

Tags: build, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, integration

We are using Bitbucket as our version control tool.
Builds and deployments are executing on Google Cloud Platform.

All builds are triggered via build triggers as specified in [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-cloud-build).
This works great, but we would like to get a build status feedback for specific branch in Bitbucket or preferably on pull request.

I did some research, but I didn't find anything useful on this specific topic.
There is a note in [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-cloud-build) considering build on pull request which doesn't give us much hope:

*"Whether based on branch commits or tag commits, builds are only triggered on pushes to the remote origin. Builds do not trigger on local changes, pre-submits, or pull requests."*

[GitHub](https://github.com/marketplace/google-cloud-build) seems to have a very good integration with Google Cloud Build which supports Build status feedback.

**Is possible to get Google Cloud Build status feedback in Bitbucket on pull request/remote push and if it is, how?
How are you dealing with this problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we've made use of, out of the box, [integration between Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/send-build-notifications) and [Google Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/). Connected into this default topic `cloud_builds` we have a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) responsible for making an `HTTP` request into [Bitbucket REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bnode%7D/statuses). This API has a current `2.0` version but several examples still mention the past version `1.0`, so be careful about the potential issues.

Comment: Thank you @MoacirRosa. In the mean time we migrated to GitLab, so I'm not able to implement your solution. However I'll accept this as an answer, because it seems the only solution as I case do far.

Comment: Thanks Dude... Hope it could help somehow. I'm not using GitLab in last years but I remember they had a rich REST APIs as well. Maybe the same idea, but using [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#post-the-build-status-to-a-commit) would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

@Moacir Rosa thank you for your answer.
Based on that suggestion we build the following GCP Cloud Function:

```
const axios = require('axios');

/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.processPubSubMessage = (event, context) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  const dataString = Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString();
  const message = JSON.parse(dataString);
  const commitSha = message.sourceProvenance.resolvedRepoSource.commitSha;
  const repoName = message.sourceProvenance.resolvedRepoSource.repoName;
  const [bitbucket, username, repo_slug] = repoName.split('_');
  // Build Bitbucket payload data.
  const payload = {
      type: 'string',
      created_on: message.createTime,
      description: `Status: ${message.status}`,
      key: 'string',
      name: 'Google Cloud Build',
      refname: `buildTriggerId: ${message.buildTriggerId}`,
      state: getBitbucketState(message.status),
      updated_on: message.finishTime,
      url: message.logUrl,
      uuid: message.id,
  }
  // Send request to Bitbucket.
  const token = process.env.BITBUCKET_TOKEN;
  const url = getBuildUrl(username, repo_slug, commitSha);
  axios.post(url, payload, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${token}` }
  })
      .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
      });


  /**
   * See: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bnode%7D/statuses/build
   * 
   * @param {string} username
   * @param {string} repo_slug
   * @param {string} commitSha 
   */
  function getBuildUrl(username, repo_slug, commitSha) {
      const baseUrl = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories';
      return `${baseUrl}/${username}/${repo_slug}/commit/${commitSha}/statuses/build`;;
  }

  /**
   * Translates states from Google Cloud Build Message to Bitbucket.
   * See: https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/commit/%7Bnode%7D/statuses/build
   * 
   * @param {string} status 
   */
  function getBitbucketState(status) {
      switch(status.toLowerCase()) {
          case 'success':
              return 'SUCCESSFUL';
          case 'queued':
          case 'working':
              return 'INPROGRESS';
          default:
              return 'FAILED';
      }
  }
};
```

See: https://github.com/honest-food-company/gcp-cloud-build-function-bitbucket

Answer (score 1):

I use Bitbucket Cloud which does not support Bitbucket Tokens. I forked Honest Food Company's excellent repo and modified it to support App Passwords for Bitbucket Cloud.

https://github.com/dgallegos/gcp-cloud-build-function-bitbucket